# Send html page by email with phpmailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send this html page via email. It's done by unlayer.com. I've tested with $mail->isHtml(true), ... msgHtml...
But in email client always see the code or part of the code instead of the html page....
Do you have any idea?
Thanks !!!

This is my code:

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Idiomes_Lin WHERE Id = 992";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


//Enviar Email
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

include ("emaildata.php");


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = SMTP_HOST;             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = SMTP_UNAME;                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD;                      // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->AuthType = 'tls';
$mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);// TCP port to connect to


$mail->From = 'it@ipe-innovaciones.com';
$mail->FromName = 'IT';

// Mail del sol·licitant
$mail->addAddress('it@ipe-innovaciones.com');     // Add a recipient

$mail->Subject = 'Test email';
$Missatge   = $row['Nom1'];
$mail->Body =  html_entity_decode($Missatge);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->send();
```

and the code I need to send is in this link: (I cannot copy paste in this input so it was weir)

https://app.guvavet.com/testenviaremail.php

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why are your entities encoded to start with? You can store raw HTML in the database without any problems. There is no such `AuthType` as `tls`; you probably don't need to set that at all. If you can't explain exactly why you're disabling TLS verification, you probably shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('yourHtml.html'), __DIR__); //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
$mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported'; // If html emails is not supported by the receiver, show this body
```